# Scrapy: crawl a site with next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Having difficulties to crawl a site with scrapy. This should be really easy, but I can't make it work:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bookstore"
    start_urls = [
    'https://example.com/materias/?novedades=LC&p',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div#results'):
            yield {
            'book_url': quote.css('ul.resultList li div.content h4 a::attr(href)').extract(),
            }

            next_page = response.css('div#paginat ul li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I run it with

```
scrapy crawl bookstore -o bookstore.json
```

It search the site, but doesn't save the results in the json file.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Any idea someone? Should be easy, but I can't understand why it isn't working!

Comment: Your original code works for me.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi! I get a 200 response, I update the question with the logs…

Comment: You are in reason, it is working now… Yesterday I tried to make it work in all the possible ways and it wasn't saving the results. Maybe I was banned or something…